# How to send Submit Button name as parameter; on form submit using JQuery/Spring MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring-mvc

When user click submit button; following method of Javacode need to executed having params ''endActivity''(which is name of Submit Button)

```
Java Code:

@Loggable
@RequestMapping(value = "save/permanent", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = { "endActivity" })
public String finalize(@ModelAttribute("MyForm") MyForm form, BindingResult br, WebRequest wr, RedirectAttributes attr) {
```

In HTML, When we give input as type submit with name endActivity, The above method gets called successfully

```
<input type="submit" name="endActivity" /> ;
```

---

Now we need to change button type from **Submit** to **Button**; as per our new requirement. So new HTML is given below:

```
<inupt type="button" name="endActivity12" /> ;
```

In JQuery; on click of button; a confirmation dialog appears with value Yes and No; on click of YES button; following script is called for dynamic submission:

```
$('#formName').append($('<input>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'endActivity').val('endActivity')).submit();
```

but Java code is not getting executed on same which means it is not getting Parameter. Can anyone help me in resolving the issue?

Comment: did you remove name from the button, before appending hidden input?

Comment: Yes. The name is different

Comment: Is there any chance to use fiddler or similar tool to check submitted data?

Comment: Can you try having a hidden element in the form, assign the button name to it and submit the form to controller.

Comment: ok Let me give a try to that. do you think will it work? and i deployed it..

Comment: I have tried the above method to send data from jsp to controller couple of times on click of button, I have had fruitful results.

Comment: and you did correct; Enjoying same fruits :) Could you please mention it in answer. The name of button and hidden element adding during submit should be same. Til i do remaining tests. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the hidden element in the form, assign name of button and submit the form to controller work for this.